# Autosys - How to setup file watcher job to find a file named with date, even if server date changes to next day

Tags: autosys

I have a file watcher job to look for a file like XXX_DONE_YYYYMMDD where YYYYMMDD is the date on which the filewatcher job kicks off. fw job waits for 4 hours for the file

e.g. Filewatcher starts on Monday 13 Sep 21 at 22:30 EST, waiting for a file XXX_DONE_20210913. I have a linux command line to look for XXX_DONE_`date +%Y%m%d`

The file is usually in before midnight, but at times it gets delayed and server date moves on to next day 14 Sep. This means if file comes in after midnight, it is not recognized and dependent jobs are not run.

How do I solve this? Is there a way to capture the date when the job kicked off to use that to look for the right filename? Is there some command or setting in autosys itself to resolve this?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of including a pattern that is dependent on a third factor, you should use `*` and have the command line look for `watch_file: "/<path>/XXX_DONE_*"`, or better use `?` which can be incorporated as `watch_file: /<path>/XXX_DONE_202?????`. Read the details [here](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/autosys-workload-automation/12-0-01/reference/ae-job-information-language/jil-job-definitions/watch-file-attribute-specify-a-file-to-monitor.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that the folder already contains similar files from previous days. I need to check for the presence of todays file only to recognise that their batch for today is complete. I dont have access to change anything in that folder (for example to delete older files before file watcher starts so that I can wait for a new file of a similar pattern).

Comment: Is there no way to capture start date of the filewatcher job to use it to get the right date? Control M has something called order date, which is accessible as a job parameter in the job. Anything similar in Autosys?

Comment: Oh!... In that case, I am not exactly sure cause most of the applications, I was part of we had access to hosts wherein the script was supposed to get triggered. Actually the script is doing what you want it to do isn't it? Captures the date as per command given, and for it to check yesterday's date despite date change requires some sort of comparison/code. Let me ask around a bit also, if senior admins can suggest something else.

Comment: Seems there's no way around this. What you can do though is chase the source to send the file before the change of date. Set a `start_time` and calculate the period till 23:59, and then put a MAX ALARM PARAMETER 30 or 45 minutes before that. Based on the mailing list, people can at least be aware that file has not been received and escalate the source to deliver it before change of date.